# In Vim, open a new window at a specified jump position

Tags: vim

In vim, my code navigation adds jumps to the jumplist (viewed with `:jumps`).

I can open a new window at previous jump number `x` by doing `CTRL-W s` followed by `x CTRL-O`; is there an existing command to achieve this faster, and if not what user-defined key mapping could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing command specifically designed for that.

In command-line mode, what you are doing can be expressed relatively simply with:

```
:split +normal\ 4^O<CR>
```

with `^O` obtained with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

But how about creating a custom mapping?

Let's start with a simple mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :split +normal\ 4^O<CR>
```

that only jumps to item #4 in the jump list. Lame.

What we would *really* like is to use `:help v:count`. For that, we need to make that dumb `:split +normal\ 4^O` smarter. This is done with `:help :execute`:

```
nnoremap <key> :execute 'split +normal\ ' . v:count . '<C-o>'<CR>
```

Our last issue is that, when we use a count before `:`, Vim automatically assumes it is a number of lines and inserts a range corresponding to that number. This is a very useful feature in general but we don't want it here because a) it doesn't represent a number of lines and b) `:execute` doesn't accept a range anyway. This is done with `:help c_ctrl-u`:

```
nnoremap <key> :<C-u>execute 'split +normal\ ' . v:count . '<C-o>'<CR>
```

which you would use like so:

```
5<key>
```